# Popup using WMS with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geoserver, wms

I would like to know how do leaflet a map coming from a geoserver be iterative and display popups with information. Please, someone could do something in the jsfiddle so I can understand, because I just can not figure out how to do this. Basically that's all I want, to bring a layer of the geoserver and be able to get information from it with popups in each part. My code is just it:

```
var stComerciaisLayer= L.tileLayer.wms("http://...:8080/geoserver/wms/", {
          layers: 'IGEO:setor_comercial_geo',
          format: 'image/png',
          transparent: true,
          attribution: "Test"
        });
```

How I put popups? Thanks!

---

I copy EXACTLY this:

http://bl.ocks.org/rclark/6908938

But dont work:

```
<script src="L.TileLayer.BetterWMS.js"></script>

var stComerciaisLayer= L.tileLayer.betterWms("http://...:8080/geoserver/wms/", {
          layers: 'IGEO:setor_comercial_geo',
          format: 'image/png',
          transparent: true,
          attribution: "Some test"
        });
```

L.TileLayer.BetterWMS.js

```
L.TileLayer.BetterWMS = L.TileLayer.WMS.extend({

  onAdd: function (map) {
    // Triggered when the layer is added to a map.
    //   Register a click listener, then do all the upstream WMS things
    L.TileLayer.WMS.prototype.onAdd.call(this, map);
    map.on('click', this.getFeatureInfo, this);
  },

  onRemove: function (map) {
    // Triggered when the layer is removed from a map.
    //   Unregister a click listener, then do all the upstream WMS things
    L.TileLayer.WMS.prototype.onRemove.call(this, map);
    map.off('click', this.getFeatureInfo, this);
  },

  getFeatureInfo: function (evt) {
    // Make an AJAX request to the server and hope for the best
    var url = this.getFeatureInfoUrl(evt.latlng),
        showResults = L.Util.bind(this.showGetFeatureInfo, this);
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        var err = typeof data === 'string' ? null : data;
        showResults(err, evt.latlng, data);
      },
      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        showResults(error);  
      }
    });
  },

  getFeatureInfoUrl: function (latlng) {
    // Construct a GetFeatureInfo request URL given a point
    var point = this._map.latLngToContainerPoint(latlng, this._map.getZoom()),
        size = this._map.getSize(),

        params = {
          request: 'GetFeatureInfo',
          service: 'WMS',
          srs: 'EPSG:4326',
          styles: this.wmsParams.styles,
          transparent: this.wmsParams.transparent,
          version: this.wmsParams.version,      
          format: this.wmsParams.format,
          bbox: this._map.getBounds().toBBoxString(),
          height: size.y,
          width: size.x,
          layers: this.wmsParams.layers,
          query_layers: this.wmsParams.layers,
          info_format: 'application/json'
        };

    params[params.version === '1.3.0' ? 'i' : 'x'] = point.x;
    params[params.version === '1.3.0' ? 'j' : 'y'] = point.y;

    return this._url + L.Util.getParamString(params, this._url, true);
  },

  showGetFeatureInfo: function (err, latlng, content) {
    if (err) { console.log(err); return; } // do nothing if there's an error

    // Otherwise show the content in a popup, or something.
    L.popup({ maxWidth: 800})
      .setLatLng(latlng)
      .setContent(content)
      .openOn(this._map);
  }
});

L.tileLayer.betterWms = function (url, options) {
  return new L.TileLayer.BetterWMS(url, options);  
};
```

The error this:

```
Failed to load http://...:8080/geoserver/wms/?REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&SERVICE=WMS&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&TRANSPARENT=true&VERSION=1.1.1&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&BBOX=-38.74431610107422%2C-4.0605082148574105%2C-38.26400756835938%2C-3.726884196645965&HEIGHT=974&WIDTH=1399&LAYERS=IGEO%3Asetor_comercial_geo&QUERY_LAYERS=IGEO%3Asetor_comercial_geo&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson&X=821&Y=172: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.



leaflet.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you show is about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

It says that your server (geoserver) is not configured to send CORS headers, therefore your browser refuses to load data from that server, sticking to the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

You should have plenty resources to configure CORS headers of your geoserver, including here on SO or on GIS Stack Exchange, e.g. [CORS - Tomcat - Geoserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363192/cors-tomcat-geoserver)