# Publishing wfs through geoserver, accessing it by openlayers3 , editing WFS and automatically saving it to postgres database

Tags: javascript, postgresql, openlayers, openlayers-3, geoserver

I am trying to access shapefile from geoserver as WFS and edit it online and at the same time it should be saved in wfs_geom table in postgres database. I have created a geometry table "wfs_geom" (columns - id, geometry) in postgres and published it through geoserver. Now trying to add point on openlayers webpage online and saving it to wfs_geom table but failing to do so.

I am trying to add points to wfs_geom with below code. This is my .js file -

```
var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();
var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
    featureNS: 'vishal',
    featureType: 'wfs_geom',
    srsName: 'EPSG:3857'
});
var xs = new XMLSerializer();
var sourceWFS = new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function (extent) {
        $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/haryana/ows?', {
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                service: 'WFS',
                version: '1.0.0',
                request: 'GetFeature',
                typename: 'wfs_geom',
                srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
                bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
            }

        }).done(function (response) {
            sourceWFS.addFeatures(formatWFS.readFeatures(response));
        });
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ()),
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
    projection: 'EPSG:3857'
});

var layerWFS = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: sourceWFS
});

var interaction;

var interactionSelectPointerMove = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove
});

var interactionSelect = new ol.interaction.Select({
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#FF2828'
        })
    })
});

var interactionSnap = new ol.interaction.Snap({
    source: layerWFS.getSource()
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    controls: [],
    interactions: [
        interactionSelectPointerMove,
        new ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom(),
        new ol.interaction.DragPan()
    ],
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM({
                url: 'https://{1-4}.aerial.maps.cit.api.here.com' +
                '/maptile//2.1/maptile/newest/hybrid.day/{z}/{x}/{y}/256/png' +
                '?app_id=TFzZOKyEry5cavZxVoe7&app_code=PLrOWVHdpxyVR_Dy0RLbnw',
                opaque: false,
                attributions: []
            })
        }),
        layerWFS
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-1.7, 53.2]),
        zoom: 12
    })
});

//wfs-t
var dirty = {};
var transactWFS = function (mode, f) {
    var node;
    switch (mode) {
        case 'insert':
            node = formatWFS.writeTransaction([f], null, null, formatGML);
            break;
        case 'update':
            node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, [f], null, formatGML);
            break;
        case 'delete':
            node = formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, null, [f], formatGML);
            break;
    }
    var payload = xs.serializeToString(node);
    $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/haryana/ows?', {
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'xml',
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'text/xml',
        data: payload
    }).done(function() {
        sourceWFS.clear();
    });
};

$('button').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('btn-active');
    $(this).addClass('btn-active');
    map.removeInteraction(interaction);
    interactionSelect.getFeatures().clear();
    map.removeInteraction(interactionSelect);

    switch ($(this).attr('id')) {

        case 'btnEdit':
            map.addInteraction(interactionSelect);
            interaction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
                features: interactionSelect.getFeatures()
            });
            map.addInteraction(interaction);
            map.addInteraction(interactionSnap);
            dirty = {};
            interactionSelect.getFeatures().on('add', function (e) {
                e.element.on('change', function (e) {
                    dirty[e.target.getId()] = true;
                });
            });
            interactionSelect.getFeatures().on('remove', function (e) {
                var f = e.element;
                if (dirty[f.getId()]) {
                    delete dirty[f.getId()];
                    var featureProperties = f.getProperties();
                    delete featureProperties.boundedBy;
                    var clone = new ol.Feature(featureProperties);
                    clone.setId(f.getId());
                    transactWFS('update', clone);
                }
            });
            break;

        case 'btnPoint':
            interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                type: 'Point',
                source: layerWFS.getSource()
            });
            map.addInteraction(interaction);
            interaction.on('drawend', function (e) {
                transactWFS('insert', e.feature);
            });
            break;

        case 'btnLine':
            interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                type: 'LineString',
                source: layerWFS.getSource()
            });
            map.addInteraction(interaction);
            interaction.on('drawend', function (e) {
                transactWFS('insert', e.feature);
            });
            break;

        case 'btnArea':
            interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                type: 'Polygon',
                source: layerWFS.getSource()
            });
            interaction.on('drawend', function (e) {
                transactWFS('insert', e.feature);
            });
            map.addInteraction(interaction);
            break;

        case 'btnDelete':
            interaction = new ol.interaction.Select();
            interaction.getFeatures().on('add', function (e) {
                transactWFS('delete', e.target.item(0));
                interactionSelectPointerMove.getFeatures().clear();
                interaction.getFeatures().clear();
            });
            map.addInteraction(interaction);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
});
$('#btnZoomIn').on('click', function() {
    var view = map.getView();
    var newResolution = view.constrainResolution(view.getResolution(), 1);
    view.setResolution(newResolution);
});

$('#btnZoomOut').on('click', function() {
    var view = map.getView();
    var newResolution = view.constrainResolution(view.getResolution(), -1);
    view.setResolution(newResolution);
});
```

this is my html page -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">
    <title>openlayers</title>

    <title>ol3-wfs-t</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/ol3-wfs-t-main.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/ol3-wfs-t-button-material.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.18.2/ol.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.18.2/ol.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<div id="thenode" style="position: absolute; top: 60px; left: 0px; width: 150px; background-color: white; z-index: 9999;">&nbsp;</div>


<button id="btnPoint" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--mini-fab mdl-button--accent">
    <i class="material-icons">add_location</i>
</button>

<button id="btnLine" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--mini-fab mdl-button--colored">
    <i class="material-icons">timeline</i>
</button>
<button id="btnArea" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--mini-fab mdl-button--colored">
    <i class="material-icons">signal_cellular_null</i>
</button>
<button id="btnEdit" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--mini-fab mdl-button--colored">
    <i class="material-icons">build</i>
</button>
<button id="btnDelete" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--mini-fab mdl-button--colored">
    <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
</button>
<button id="btnZoomIn" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--mini-fab mdl-button--colored">
    <i class="material-icons">zoom_in</i>
</button>
<button id="btnZoomOut" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-button--mini-fab mdl-button--colored">
    <i class="material-icons">zoom_out</i>
</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index3.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

points drawn are not updated in postgres table.

Comment: can you add examples of the XML file sent to the server and the response you get back. Also please look in the GeoServer log file and see if there are any error messages and add those too.

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210109/enabling-cors-in-geoserver-jetty or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363192/cors-tomcat-geoserver

Comment: <wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:iirs="vishal" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd vishal http://localhost:8080/geoserver/iirs/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&typeName=iirs%3Awfs_geom">
<gml:boundedBy>
<gml:null>unknown</gml:null>
</gml:boundedBy>
</wfs:FeatureCollection>

Comment: my .xml file appers like above

Comment: Now my CORS error is gone and I can see ows file in response, but it's not getting entered into the database. Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: please ask a new question if you have further problems